# JS date compare issue

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, compare, difference

I want to compare a init time with current time and results are weird.

From a String a build a date like shown:

```
fechIni = "2019-02-07"
timeIni = "17:40"
var datepartsIni = fechIni.split("-");
var horapartsIni = timeIni.split(":");
var dateIni = new Date(datepartsIni[0], datepartsIni[1], datepartsIni[2], horapartsIni[0], horapartsIni[1]);
```

if print dateIni, I got something like: Thu Mar 07 2019 17:40:00 GMT-0300 (hora de verano de Chile) Witch I think is right.

Then, I compare that date with current date (for not allowing doing something).

```
var currentdate = new Date();
```

When I compared them, (imagine dateIni is earlier than currentdate) with something like this:

```
if (dateIni > currentdate) {... do stuff ...}
```

I got true when it should be false. I have try with .valueOf(), convert to milis, convert to epoch and calculating difference... but I can't do the trick.

I attach a screenshot of console output and code.

[image: Code]

[image: Code2]

UPDATE:
Solved!! The trick was setting the date:

```
var dateFin = new Date(datepartsFin[0], datepartsFin[1] - 1, datepartsFin[2], horapartsFin[0], horapartsFin[1]);
```

Instead of

```
var dateFin = new Date(datepartsFin[0], datepartsFin[1], datepartsFin[2], horapartsFin[0], horapartsFin[1]); //WRONG in my case
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Mar 07 is indeed > Feb 07. What did you expect?

Comment: The months are indexed from 0 in date. So "02" means March and not February

Comment: i would parse it as a js-known string, like ISO or GMT, so that timezones aren't wrong like when you feed Date() a bunch of numbers.

Comment: I didn't realised of that @wolfram42 thanks!!

Comment: I was obfuscated on day and time than I didn't realised of month. Developing storys...

Comment: Confused as you say that (dateIni > currentdate) is true but should be false. Your dateIni is in the future not the past. The valueOf returns a number that is greater the further away from the epoch (or 0). So this means that dates in the future are a greater value than the present. Your if statement should return true.